# ItemSelector and Porting content

Tags: 2011, 2013, itemselector

Long time back one of our team started using item selector and it is still in place in tridion 2011 sp1 version. Now we are planning to upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1 keeping the current DTAP environment in parallel. Since item selector has been extensively used across some 1000 compoents having link to a Page where it is being used. It is posing a problem for porting such content as item selector returns back the tcm-id of page into the text field of component and this would be invalid in the new environment.

We are planning for a app which would give us the list of components and the respective linked page webdav path in XML, which we can use in destination for linking to the page using core services.  Is there any better or faster solution other than this? As developing this might consume sometime.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you have a new Tridion 2013 SP1 environment that you are porting content in to (from the Tridion 2011 SP1 environment).

Rather than doing this, **you could upgrade the Tridion 2011 SP1 environment's Tridion_cm database**, and then use that database in your new 2013 SP1 environment.

Upgrading the original Tridion 2011 SP1 database this way will maintain your TcmId references.

**NOTE:** In Tridion 2013 SP1, you get to 'decommission' Publishing Targets. This should help with deleting anything that you no longer need from your original Tridion 2011 SP1 Content Manager.

Comment: We have lot of development going on and we can't disturb the existing one. hence have been asked to start upgrade in parallel.

Comment: Can't you start the upgrade in parallel, with a copy of your production database instead of a new one?

Comment: No @NunoLinhares as our DB is also getting upgraded from Oracle to SQL :(

Comment: @sri If you are moving from Oracle to SQL Server, as you describe, then creating a TcmId -> WebDav -> TcmId Core Service tool is probably your best option. You may need to be careful how you architect this, if your tool can't see both environments simultaneously. I would probably suggest doing it in two passes (an export of 2011 TcmId to WebDav mappings and then an import/update of the TcmIds in the 2013 environment) anyway.